# Why can't I create videos or send video data over the internet?

Tags: python, sockets, video, byte, decode

## Info

I've been really wanting to be able to send image and video data over the internet using sockets in Python. But I don't know how to read videos and decode the `bytes`.

#### So I got an idea today and tried it out:

```py
with open('VID_READ.mp4', 'rb') as vid_read:
    # 'rb' to read the video data as bytes and avoid codec errors
    byte_data = vid_read.read()
    str_data = str(byte_data)[2:-1] # To avoid codec errors caused by byte decoding
    vid_read.close()

with open('VID_WRITE.mp4', 'w') as vid_write:
    vid_write.write(str_data)
```

The code above finishes without any errors, but when I try to open `VID_WRITE.mp4` with a video player, I get a read error.

## Question

> How do I read the byte data in a video, decode it, and write it into another video file without any errors?

Comment: if you want decode then you should use specialized modules for this which usually use `ffmpeg`. Using only `open()` you can't do this.

Comment: if you only want to send data then you don't have to decode it but read bytes and send as is. Socket sends bytes - there is no need to convert bytes to string

Comment: don't convert to string and don't cut `[2:-1]` but write all as is and use `wb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket sends bytes so there is no need to convert to string.

And don't convert to string files like `image` or `video` because it changes some bytes (`new line`) and it can destroy data. And don't cut `[2:-1]` because you create incomplete data.

Simply read as bytes `rb` and write as bytes `wb`

```
with open('VID_READ.mp4', 'rb') as vid_read:
      byte_data = vid_read.read()

# ... send bytes using socket ...

with open('VID_WRITE.mp4', 'wb') as vid_write:
      vid_write.write(byte_data)
```

---

**BTW:** If you use `with open(...) as ..` then you don't need `close()` because `with` closes it.

---

**BTW:**

If you want to convert or edit `video` or `image` then use specialized modules like `PIL` / [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) / [wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.1/) for images, [MoviePy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/index.html) / [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) for video. You can't do it using standard `open()`

Comment: Thanks! I know that sockets send bytes, but what if I want to decode the bytes after I receive them?

Comment: I actually didn't know what `wb` meant, but now I get it: `Write Bytes`. And it actually worked out! Thank you so much!

Comment: here is example which use `socket` to send image with current time created with `PyGame` and client displays it: https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/socket-send-receive-image